# Replace em dash with hyphen while reading excel files in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

i am reading an excel file using panda data frames. Column names may contain hyphen or em dash. i would like to replace all em dash with hyphen so that i can read column values with hyphen. row ['abc-def'].

Answer (score 1):

Hyphen or em dash, you can still read the columns (a string is a string!) But if you insist, here's how to fix the dashes:

```
df.columns = [c.replace("–", "-") for c in df]
```